# An image calls an ASP utility. How do I do that without image in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a store (C#) that calls our "back office(ASP classic)" via a one-pixel image with some parameters to record a sale.  It looks like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="BOImageLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://backoffice.mysite.com/Import.asp?TicketType=Import"></asp:Image>
```

The store's code-behind appends other parameters to the ImageUrl as needed.

About once per day someone gets through the system without triggering the image tag link.  My task is to make the call to that script from our store which is ASP.NET C# code without using an image tag and I just don't know how to do it.  All help appreciated, answering accordingly knowing I am new to .NET is doubly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really random way of doing that! 
Why don't you do a web request in code instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9y35bd.aspx

Would be something like this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("https://backoffice.mysite.com/Import.asp?TicketType=Import");
```

using this to get back any response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
```

Comment: I agree about it being random but it is the system in place when I inherited this project.  WebRequest is exactly what I need.  Thanks for the pointer to the right direction and the examples!